# CSS. How center with flex an element respecting display width instead available free space

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want an element (100px) centered on the display. This element has on each side elements with eg 300px and 200px.

I did it with flex an as a result there are 2 free spaces / flexible width elements. Centered element is centered in the free space no with the whole display width. You can see it in the image as well at [codepen](http://codepen.io/M1k3l/pen/bpqXbg).

I want 100px box (as in green row) in the middle. I am not using float left/right for side elements and then center middle element because I need to apply a background image to flexible width elements.

The [codepen](http://codepen.io/M1k3l/pen/bpqXbg).

[image]

```css
html, body, div {
  width: 100%;
}

.row {
  height: 100px;
}
.row.row-flex {
  display: flex;
}
.row.row-green {
  background-color: green;
}
.row.row-red {
  background-color: red;
}

.col {
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}
.col.col-100 {
  width: 100px;
}
.col.col-200 {
  width: 200px;
}
.col.col-300 {
  width: 300px;
}
.col.col-flex {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="row row-flex row-red">
  <div class="col col-300">300px</div>
  <div class="col col-flex"></div>
  <div class="col col-100">100px</div>
  <div class="col col-flex"></div>
  <div class="col col-200">200px</div>
</div>

<div class="row row-green">
  <div class="col col-100">100px</div>
</div>
```

Comment: So do you want the 300px and 200px elements to disappear, or to just not influence the position of the 100px div?

Comment: if this situation (width of asides elements known) you may either add a negative margin towards the center element (first of 300 + margin-right:-100px; http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XdReLN or add these 100px difference on last one margin-left:100px; http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BKRwgb .col base margin is 0; and .col-100 is 0 auto; Empty divs in between are not needed

Comment: Are you putting content in the `.col-flex` elements are are they just there as spacers?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I think absolute positioning is the way. Flex positions its children in a way that each gets fair share of free space. Add

```
row {position: relative;}
```

and

```
&.col-100{position: absolute; top: 0; left: calc(50% - 50px);}
```

to align 100px div against whole row.

Edited codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pRwOYv